# Are boost::spirit pointer attributes initialized with nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost-spirit

I think I saw in a debugger somewhere that a `boost::spirit` attribute of some pointer-type was set to `nullptr`, but I didn't do that. Was that just coincidence or does `boost::spirit` actually take care of initializing pointer-type attributes?

Currently I put an `eps [ _val = nullptr ]` at the start of a rule when I need to be sure, but it would be nice to know so I could omit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does boost::spirit actually take care of initializing pointer-type attributes?

Effectively, yes.

Spirit uses a `make_attribute`. The comment seems to indicate this would only happen for semantic actions, but it's actually also used inside the `rule` parser (but what gets passed to subparser expressions might be transformed).

`make_attribute` uses the [`boost::value_initialized` trait](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm):

> Constructing and initializing objects in a generic way is difficult in C++. The problem is that there are several different rules that apply for initialization. Depending on the type, the value of a newly constructed object can be zero-initialized (logically 0), default-constructed (using the default constructor), or indeterminate. When writing generic code, this problem must be addressed. The template value_initialized provides a solution with consistent syntax for value initialization of scalar, union and class types. Moreover, value_initialized offers a workaround to various compiler issues regarding value-initialization. Furthermore, a const object, initialized_value is provided, to avoid repeating the type name when retrieving the value from a value_initialized object.

So, barring any custom defined specializations in your code, the default behavior does offer value-initialization.